# node.js Date - ISODate is offset when Zulu not passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

Regardless of system timezone, when `Z` is not appended to an ISODate string, the Date is resolving to 5 hour difference. I can't find anything in the Date constructor spec saying  `.toISOString()` would resolve to anything but GMT.

I have tried setting my system timezone multiple times, all resulting in the same offset of five hours. Using moment/moment-timezone is also exhibiting the same behavior. What am I missing here?

```
> Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
   'Asia/Katmandu'
> new Date("2022-08-04T19:00:00").toISOString()   ## <-- no 'Z' appended
   '2022-08-04T14:00:00'                          ## <-- 5 hour difference
> new Date("2022-08-04T19:00:00Z").toISOString(). ## <-- with 'Z'
   '2022-08-04T19:00:00.000Z'                     ## <-- no difference
```

Answer (score 1):

Your environment’s time zone is set to Asia/Katmandu.

When you call `new Date("2022-08-04T19:00:00")` without the `Z` it is assuming the date/time you’re passing in is in Katmandu time (as if you had actually passed in `"2022-08-04T19:00:00+0500"`). When you call `.toISOString()` it converts that Katmandu time to UTC by subtracting five hours.

My system is set to America/New_York, so if I call the exact same code I get `2022-08-04T23:00:00.000Z` back out.

When you call `new Date("2022-08-04T19:00:00Z")` *with* the `Z` you are explicitly saying the date/time you’re passing in is in UTC already, so when you call `.toISOString()` you get the same time back out.

Comment: @davecarwell - Right - the problem is regardless of system timezone - i'm still getting the same 5 hour offset after changing the timezone and restarting my machine.

```
> Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
'Asia/Ashgabat'
> new Date("2022-08-04T19:50:49").toISOString()
'2022-08-04T14:50:49.000Z'
> new Date("2022-08-04T19:50:49Z").toISOString()
'2022-08-04T19:50:49.000Z'
```

Comment: @MichaelPaszkiewicz Isn’t Asia/Ashgabat also UTC+5 though…? What about if you set the timezone to something like Europe/London?